# Symmetrical perspective with Free Transform in Illustrator CS5?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, perspective

In **Adobe Illustrator CS5**:

I want a "depth effect" to an object with the **straight-from-the-front perspective**. But with the `Free Transform`-tool it seems to only be possible to drag one corner each time to the middle which makes it very hard to get it symmetrical.

Is there any way to get it symmetrical?

[image]

**Edit:**

I've tired to place a centred rectangle to have something to snap to. But it turns out that when I drag the other corner, the first corner then change position:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Press `Cmd + alt + Shift` when you're dragging.

**Note:** You need to **first click and hold or start dragging** the anchor before you can do the command above.

Comment: +1.. this is it.. but the **order** of the clicking/key pressing/dragging is **very important**, as you posted. This works in all versions of AI, even versions newer than CS5.

Comment: @Scott Maybe so, but maybe it's easier in newer versions? Maybe like in my Photoshop for example, that actually is CS5 so I don't understand why they didn't had the same in Illustrator. But there you just choose Transform > Perspective and the above thing is what's happening.

Comment: Illustrator is not Photoshop `:)` And be aware, CS5 is more than a decade old. They have improved things since CS5.

Comment: @Scott Yes, but it was just the reason why I didn't know how it was done in Illustrator. I didn't know that command and I think it's kind of weird that they have features that only exist in commands and can't be done with the GUI. And yes, it's very old. Sadly I don't have the budget to pay for a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Place a centered helper shape, eg. a rectangle, on top to have something to snap to.

Comment: I tried that but it turns out that when I drag the other corner, the first corner then change position. See my edit above.

Comment: Try using it on the lower end, then you can avoid the distortion.

Comment: You also might want to apply "Outline Stroke" on the curved line, to better scale in perspective.

Comment: I found the solution. See my edit above. And yes, during this time I actually googled for how to get the lines correct and found just that answer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @PeterWesterlund Cool, you might post your Edit 2 as an answer and mark it as solution, so it's officially filed as done.

Answer (score 0):

Select the **Free Transform Tool**

[image]

and choose the **Perspective Distort** option

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer. But sadly I can't see a Perspective Distort option in Illustrator CS5. Maybe there is anywhere. But where?

Comment: Does Cmd/alt/shift drag also work in Illustrator, same as in Photoshop? [presumably ctrl/alt/shift on Windows]

Comment: @PeterWesterlund Check it again, apparently the perspective distortion option is there from the [Illustrator CC](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2115289&seqNum=27) version

Comment: @Danielillo I found the answer myself. See my edit above. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Pretty sure I said that half an hour ago… I just don't have Illustrator to test on. Can you provide your answer as an **answer** not as an edit to your question.